# Jpanel's visibility issue inside jLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing

My code cannot display the desired JPanel which initially has setVisible(false) but when some action is performed its visibility is then set to true but it is not displayed on the screen.

Even if I set setVisible to true initially it does not display. I've attached the code on PasteBin [here](http://pastebin.com/UTyr38yz)

There are 2 layered panes, one is jLayeredPane1 and the other is jLayeredPane2. Now, in JLayeredPane1 there are two JPanels, the recordingPanel and the reRecordingPanel.

Initially when the applet is loaded reRecordingPanel's visibility is setVisible(false). When the first round of recording completes it becomes visible and recordingPanel which was visible becomes now invisible. This is working fine.

My issue is i want to do the same on the other JLayeredPanel which contains timerPanel and listeningPanel inside of it.

**Here is the problem**: timerPanel's visibility is true initially *but when the user presses Listen button it should be invisible and listening Panel should be visible* but this is not the case!

I can not see the listening player though i have set its visibility to true. As I said earlier even if I set its visibility initially to true it is not displayed.

What did I do wrong ?

Is it to do with race conditions?

the problem is in this code snippet

```
if (getCurrentState() == RecorderUI.LISTENING_STATE) {

            // switch panel
            this.timerPanel.setVisible(true);
            this.listeningPanel.setVisible(false);

            // switch button
            this.reRecordingButton.setEnabled(true);
            this.saveButton.setEnabled(true);

            this.listenButton.setText("Listen");

            this.setCurrentState(NORMAL_STATE);

            // according to player's state wise
            this.closePlayer();

            log.info(" player closed ");

        } else {

            // switch panel
            this.timerPanel.setVisible(false);
            this.listeningPanel.setVisible(true);

            log.info(" visibility of listeningPanel is "
                    + this.listeningPanel.isVisible());

            // switch button
            this.reRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);
            this.saveButton.setEnabled(false);

            this.listenButton.setText("Close");

            this.setCurrentState(LISTENING_STATE);

            this.startPlayer();

            log.info(" now playing ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `this.timerpanel.setVisible(false)` instead of `timerPanel.setVisible(false)` ? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Pureferret `this` refers to the current instance of the class. In some case it can help disambiguate a class variable from a method parameter (typically a set-method). It is also used in other cases...

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I know how `this` works, but `this.somethingElse.someMethod` says to me perform `someMethod` on the *public variable* `somethingElse` belonging to `this` (or in this case it could be private). I didn't think you could do `this.instance`. Perhaps it's too early in the morning.

Comment: @Pureferret In this case, the keyword is unnecessary since there is no ambiguity. Some developpers like to put them all the time to prevent a possible future name clash.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet but it's valid? Darn, I though I could answer someone else's question for once.

Comment: nearly 2000 loc? Strip it down to about 50 to 100 to isolate the problem, or in other words: show an SSCCE instead of that monster :-)

Comment: @Pureferret You can always precede accesses to member variables or methods with the `this.` keyword. Typically, it is redundant and will make no difference (assuming there are no naming collisions between instance variables and local variables). However, it is never invalid.

Comment: Mr. kleopatra i have already explained the problem in my description. i have posted whole code because any one can run at his/her side.please suggest me a solution instead of this unnecessary debates of this key word.

Comment: @Mihir You have explained the problem, yes, but the problem could be nearly *anywhere* in those 2000 lines. Using a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) helps us find the problem, and help you.

Comment: *"the problem is in this code snippet"* Prove it by making the snippet an SSCCE.

Comment: ok now i edited the question and add the code snnipate whic is not working as expected for panel's visibility.

Comment: -1 for insisting on not providing an SSCCE (and the _Mr._ <g>)

Answer (score 0):

**while debugging i found matisse has set heigth and widht of the jPanel (listeningPanel) to -1,-1 that is why it is not displayed on the screen . i have solved it by setting its manually** .

Thank You All